# How to create Nexus 5 Android emulator by using command line

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I have Android SDK installed and I want to create Nexus 5 emulator by using command line. I can't use Android Studio Virtual Device Manager.

To create an emulator I am using such command:

```
avdmanager create avd -n Nexus5_API24 -k "system-images;android-24;googl
e_apis;x86" --tag "google_apis"
```

The problem is that such command creates default emulator without any skin. As I understand, if I want to set the skin I have to specify `targetId` of existing skins by using `-t` flag (according to this documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html)

When I execute `avdmanager list` command I can find that my `targetId` is 8:

```
id: 8 or "Nexus 5"
Name: Nexus 5
OEM : Google
```

But `-t` flag somehow doesn't exist in reality for the command `create avd` and I get such error when I try to use it:

```
Error: Flag '-t' is not valid for 'create avd'.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Add `--device "Nexus 5"` param

Comment: Although `--device "Nexus 5"`  helps, it doesn't actually work to fix the problem - the skin (resolution, DPI, etc.) aren't specified as a result.